# asp.net mvc, wrong function being fired. - EDITED

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have master page that has this control that accepts Post verb.  My LogOn page is also tied to the master page. When I enter wrong username/password, method of that control that accepts verb also gets fired along with the method to accept username password.

This is on HomeConroller:

```
 [ActionName("ControlTemp"), AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult ControlTemp(TempClass temp)
        {
           return PartialView("ControlTemp"); 
        }
```

This is on AccountController:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1054:UriParametersShouldNotBeStrings",
            Justification = "Needs to take same parameter type as Controller.Redirect()")]
        public ActionResult LogOn(string userName, string password, bool rememberMe, string returnUrl)
        {

            if (!ValidateLogOn(userName, password))
            {
                return View();
            }

            FormsAuth.SignIn(userName, rememberMe);
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
```

Now, why do you think things are being posted to ControlTemp too?

EDIT: This is how I am referring to ControlTemp control on masterpage.

```
            <div id = "divControlTemp">  <% Html.RenderAction("ControlTemp", "Home"); %></div>
```

So after watching debugger, I saw it returns View() if username/password is invalid.  It then hits the divControlTemp control, but instead of firing 
`public ActionResult ControlTemp()`, it fires

```
[ActionName("ControlTemp"), AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
            public ActionResult ControlTemp(TempClass temp)
```

and that is all I can see from the debugger.  So my question is why do you think it thinks it is a post? Is it because the reurn View() was called from a method that was accepting Post verb?

Comment: I do not think ValidateLogOn is the issue, but it's the default code that came up with mvc project.  I coded ControlTemp code though.  I was thinking maybe I misunderstand how "Post" verb works.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is "can a single http requests fire two separate action methods", the answer is no. Unless of course there is a redirect from one action method to the other or one of the methods calls the other directly. If there are redirections, you can see them in the [Firebug](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&ved=0CAkQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Faddons.mozilla.org%2Fde%2Ffirefox%2Faddon%2F1843&ei=IF9rS_qVDpGOnAOOi7n4BA&usg=AFQjCNHyQAWEpGcI0dV2eGI6lS18torYJw&sig2=dp3d6AGyYH_CJB_pLrziug) console.

But frankly, if this was my software, I'd simply fire up the debugger and see what's going wrong. It shouldn't be too difficult to spot the problem this way.

Comment: and just so you know controltemp is a partial view